# php pharData unable to open new phar

Tags: php

I am creating a .tar extension file using PharData. It works on my computer but it failed on the server.

Error message: unable to open new phar /bla/bla/firstDirectory/secondDirectory/otherFiles/ for writing

How can I solve the problem?

```
$tarFilePath = realpath($tarFolderPath)."/".$tarFileName;
$phar        = new PharData($tarFilePath);
$phar->buildFromDirectory(realpath($FILE_DIR . "/../../firstDirectory/secondDirectory/otherFiles/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the mode to your project directory it should be **755**.

If it's **755**, then just overwrite it with the same mode permissions, **755**.

If everything else fails, use **777** (be careful not to use this on the server).